# innerHTML не даёт результата

Tags: javascript, html

Текст не появляется на странице. В консоли ошибок нет. В чем проблема?
page.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Javascript</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <script type="text/javascript">photoInsert();</script>

</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```js
function photoInsert() {
 var number = 1,
  box,
  boxname ='box'+number;

  box = document.createElement("div");
  box.id = boxname;
  box.innerHTML = '<p>TEXT</p>';

  alert('ok');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что созданный элемент не добавлен на страницу, если его добавить, то можно будет увидеть результат. Для вставки можно использовать функцию [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

```js
function photoInsert() {
  var number = 1,
    box,
    boxname = 'box' + number;

  box = document.createElement("div");
  box.id = boxname;
  box.innerHTML = '<p>TEXT</p>';

  document.body.appendChild(box);
}

photoInsert()
```

Comment: Возможно вопрос нелепый, но если метод "innerHTML" не добавляет элемент на страницу, то что он делает вообще? Разве код "<p>TEXT</p>" не стал частью страницы и не расположился внутри созданного div-а? (appendChild использовал, спасибо)

Comment: @AlexeyLyulenkov, как следует из названия свойства _innerHTML_ - оно ответственно за то, что лежит **внутри** элемента. Элемент в данном случае - `box`, который создается. После создания он никак не связан с DOM деревом, которое показывается браузером, чтобы он тоже стал показываться, его надо в это дерево добавить

Comment: Ну точно... понял. Большое спасибо.